# How does this python script see the correct column?

Tags: python

I am running this script with great success but was curious about how it is referencing the data. (How else am I to learn?)

```
input_file = Cars.csv    
with open(input_file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    cars_list = tuple([row[1] for row in reader])

template_cars ="C:\\Data\\CarsTemplate.txt"
cars_textfile = "C:\\Data\\Cars.txt"
shutil.copyfile(template_cars,cars_textfile)

with open(cars_textfile, 'a') as f:
    if len(cars_list) == 0:
        cars_Sentence = ""

    elif len(cars_list) == 1:
        cars_Sentence = "A  %s is parked on the street." % cars_list

    elif len(cars_list) == 2:
        cars_Sentence = "Cars %s and %s are parked on the street." % cars_list

    else:
        for record in cars_list:
            cars_Sentence = "Cars " + ('%s, ' * (len(cars_list)-1) + 'and %s') % tuple(cars_list) + " are parked on the street"

    f.write(cars_Sentence)
f.close()
```

My Cars.csv file's data:

```
RecNo,Model,ItemNo,Count  
1,Prius,1,1  
2,Civic,2,3  
3,Lexus,1,5  
4,Jetta,5,1  
5,Subaru,0,0
```

Given the code above, which works for my data, how does it know to print out the Model column and not the other colums? I figure it has something to do with the column containing strings rather than numbers.

If my data had two columns of strings instead of one, how would I just reference the column I want and output the same results? Just curious. Trying to get my head around coding.

Again, thanks to all that help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often one can improve code quite a bit to become more robust and more readable
by reading (here: the csv module) documentation and choosing correctly.

Note, that in your CSV file the first line indicates the field names; it is skipped by the 
next(reader) call of your code.

Chosing the optimum class you dont have to skip it, but is is evaluated to get access to these fieldnames and the first section becomes:

```
with open(input_file) as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
   cars_list = tuple([row["Model"] for row in reader])
```

This makes quite obvious, where to change to get different information and also would work for files, where the "Model" column is differently placed.

Comment: Awesome! I'm changing it now. This will really help with my memory lapses.

Answer (score 1):

Only the model column is taken from the file:

```
cars_list = tuple([row[1] for row in reader])
```

This takes each line from your input (which the csv module turns into a sequence of columns)  and takes only the second column (python uses 0-based indexing).

In other words, whomever wrote this code knew that each line in the input file contains four columns and is picking out just the second one. If a different column contained the model, you'd have to adjust the `row[1]` index.

Comment: Ha. I referenced this this myself but forgot why. Gettin old is tough sometimes.... Thanks.